# php - Script Not Working After Being Uploaded To Live Server

Tags: php, linux, filepath

I am developing a php script locally using `XAMPP`, it is working on my local server, but after being uploaded to the linux live server, there are many things those won't work. Most of the problems are caused by file path writing.

**For example:**

`require('inc/config.php')` working in `XAMPP` but it does not work on live server or vice versa. So I need to change it to `require('config.php')` in order to make it able to be called on live server.

That seem like ruining the whole of my works and make the times I invested become useless.

**My question:**

1. What's the common solution can I use to prevent that kind of problem? Is using full path to call a file the best practice?
2. Is there any local development environment for Windows like `XAMPP` that able to simulate linux server structure, so there will be nothing need to be fixed after finishing development on local server then upload it to linux live server?

Please somebody help..

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change anything, just in the index.php give your script proper path to your scripts using [set_include_path()](https://www.php.net/set_include_path).